# NSOperation thread running in background, causes a UITableView or UIScrollView or UIWebView scrolling rough(Not smooth as it would be usually.)

Tags: iphone

NSOperation thread running in background, causes a  UITableView or UIScrollView or UIWebView  scrolling rough(Not smooth as it would be usually.)

How can i solve this problem ??

There is no connection between UITableView datasource and delegates and thread which is running in background. Both uses independent resources.

How to solve this problem ??

Comment: Can you post some relevant code? It's kinda hard to understand the problem.

Comment: Sorry, i can not post code, because it is confidential.

Comment: But i have a situation like this: when application starts, i used a NSInvocationOperation (thread) to determine current lat, long of device, this process is running in background. mean while user navigates to another screen which holds UITable.UItableCell contains only text value. Nothing more than that. When i navigate to TableView screen and scrolling table it scrolls hard not smooth as it would be.

Comment: But when i disable that background running thread in UIApplication Delegate then UITableView scrolls smooth.

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone has only a single processor core, so the execution of any background threads (such as those used by `NSOperation`) is interleaved with UI rendering and other operations. The work being done by your operation is sufficiently demanding that the CPU hasn't enough time left over to run the scrolling/rendering logic fast enough to give a smooth result. Basically, you need to do less. However, you might get some milage out of changing the thread priority of your `NSOperation` instance; something like...

```
[myOperation setThreadPriority:0.1];
```

This should push the scheduler to prioritise other threads (such as the rest of your code and the UI rendering operations) over your background operation.

The other alternative is to make your scrolled rendering workloads (i.e. `UITableView` cells) more efficient. For the table case, if you're using cells with many sub `UIView`s you can try and replace them with cells that use i.e. just images.

Comment: Then, bluntly, you're just doing more than the iPhone's resources can handle. What's happening in your `NSOperation`?

Comment: just finding current location lat, long value and when it finds it just Notifies ViewControllerObject(which also holds UITableView).

Comment: What's your test iPhone/iPod version?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the hardware version. GPS usage on an iPhone 3G is, for no reason I can think of, a cause of *huge* system wide lag.

Answer (score 2):

I had recently given up on finding a solution to the same problem. But it just occurred to me that you might be able to use KVO to watch the `decelerating` and `tracking` properties of the table view, and if either is true then suspend the operation queue.  That won't stop any operations that have already started, but at least it won't start any new ones.  Then you can resume the queue when the tableview is no longer tracking or decelerating.

This is all completely speculation though.  I would try it myself if I had the time...

Comment: once operation suspended when tableview declerating and tracking then how to start that suspended operation ??? and when to start ??

Comment: Wait, are you just using an NSOperation as a lone thread? If so, my answer may not be relevant

Answer (score 0):

i am working with an application which is accessing huge amount of data in background

what i observed in my application that all operations are independent but there is continuous data synchronization with tableview is there

thats why it feels like chopping issue

as soon as data uploading to tableview completed... tableview scroll works fine

So there is only one way you can fetch data in batches like [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:30];

Comment: But in my case, there is no relation in between background thread and Tableview data source, and even after completion of an execution of background thread, still chopping problem with UITableView is there, actually not only UITableView, i have stuck with chopping issue with any GUI component. (like UIPickerView, UIScrollview, UITextView...)